# Convert '%23' to '#' in PHP

Tags: php, hashtag, htmlspecialchars

URL: **example.com/search:#searchWord**

Since the `#` is not send to the server, it is changed to `%23`.

In the search page I want to display

**Results for: #searchWord**

But what I get is `%23searchWord`. I tried `htmlspecialchars()`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you not just replace all the instances yourself?

Comment: Also, [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) if it's just that one entity.

Comment: urldecode() do the trick . Thanks Aurelio :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your goal use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo urlencode('example.com/search:#searchWord');
// output: example.com%2Fsearch%3A%23searchWord

echo urldecode('example.com%2Fsearch%3A%23searchWord');
// output: example.com/search:#searchWord
```